# Composite keys, EF6 and insert order

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework

I have a problem with EF6 and composite keys. Assume that I have a class (TableInBetween) that has a composite key consisting of two foreign keys (primary key of ClassA and ClassB). In order to insert several of those TableInBetweens in the database, I need to make sure that ClassA and ClassB has been inserted and gotten a value for their primary key. EF6 seems to have trouble figuring that out and attempts to insert all TableInBetween objects with ClassAId = 0 and/or ClassBId = 0. The easiest solution is to insert first all ClassAs and Bs by calling SaveChanges() and then create TableInBetweens that reuse those existing database ids. However, that is a classic dirty solution and might be not an option for cases where you need to do a bulk insert for whatever reason.

**So, the question is:** How do I indicate that ClassA and ClassB need to have a primary Id set before attempting to save the TableInBetween?

```
[Table("CLASSA")]
public class ClassA
{
    [Column("ID"), Key]
    public int Id {get; set;}
    .
    .
    .

    public ICollection<TableInBetween> InBetweens { get; set; }
}

[Table("CLASSB")]
public class ClassB
{
    [Column("ID"), Key]
    public int Id {get; set;}
    .
    .
    .

    public ICollection<TableInBetween> InBetweens { get; set; }
}

[Table("TABLE_IN_BETWEEN")]
public class TableInBetween
{
    [Column("CLASS_A_ID", Order = 1), Key]
    public int ClassAId {get; set;}

    [Column("CLASS_B_ID", Order = 2), Key]
    public int ClassBId {get; set;}

    .
    .
    .

    [ForeignKey("ClassAId")]
    public virtual ClassA ClassA {get; set;}

    [ForeignKey("ClassBId")]
    public virtual ClassB ClassB {get; set;}    
}
```

Important: It looks like depending on the model this might work sometimes without doing something explicitely. It seems like EF is sorting it out for some models, but not for others.

Comment: Many to many relationship with a composite key is what you are looking for http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/configure-many-to-many-relationship-in-ef-core.aspx also, why make all your tables and friends uppercase with underscore

Comment: @TheGeneral: Let me have a look. To answer your question on the table names, the target database is oracle in this case and we are required to use that convension.

Comment: @TheGeneral: Thanks! I solved it! Basically, the problem remains if you try to bulk insert things, but that is not my use case. Maybe I missed something, but at least I have solved my issue for several such relationships in the database.

Comment: Im glad to hear it